# Scala spark, show distinct column value and count number of occurrence

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to look at parquet files and would like to show the number of distinct value of a column and the number of rows it is found in.

The SQL equivalent is:

```
select distinct(last_name), count(*) from optimization.opt_res group by (last_name)
```

In scala-spark (displays them separately):

```
val dataFrame = sparkSession.read.parquet(fname)
dataFrame.show(truncate = false)
val disID = dataFrame.select("last_name").distinct()
disID.show(false)
val disCount = disID.count
```

I want it to show

```
+-----------+-------+
| last_name | count |
+-----------+-------+
| Alfred    |   202 |
| James     |  1020 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataframe.groupBy($"last_name").agg(count("*"))`

or

`dataframe.groupBy($"last_name").count`

The concept is the same as SQL, but the syntax can be a bit tricky until you get used to it.